# FFmpeg: SSIM Returning Unexpected Result When Input is Using MKV Container

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

I have an uncompressed video file and I want to compress it with a (lossless) codec.

It is all right, but when I perform SSIM test, FFmpeg is returning an unexpected result (i.e. SSIM <> 1) when the input video is using a MKV container.

Here is what I am doing:

First, I compress the (uncompressed) input video file by using a lossless codec (it can be any) to five different (and compatible) containers:

`ffmpeg -i input.y4m -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 -g 1 h264.mkv`

`ffmpeg -i input.y4m -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 -g 1 h264.mp4`

`ffmpeg -i input.y4m -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 -g 1 h264.ts`

`ffmpeg -i input.y4m -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 -g 1 h264.avi`

`ffmpeg -i input.y4m -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 -g 1 h264.nut`

Then, I perform SSIM test on the output videos:

`ffmpeg -i <input> -i rawvideo.y4m \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[compressed]; \
[1:v]settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[rawvideo]; \
[compressed][rawvideo]ssim" -f null -`

Now, the problem is:

For **all** containers, except the MKV, I get the expected result of:

`SSIM Y:1.000000 (inf) U:1.000000 (inf) V:1.000000 (inf) All:1.000000 (inf)`

But for MKV I get the following (unexpected) result:

`SSIM Y:0.963931 (14.428696) U:0.994818 (22.855238) V:0.994708 (22.763531) All:0.974209 (15.885241)`

Am I missing something? I'm using Linux Debian 10.

Comment: Instead of `PTS-STARTPTS`, use `setpts=N`. Of course, you could just have different no. of frames in the MKV.

Comment: OK, it worked. It is correct now: `SSIM Y:1.000000 (inf) U:1.000000 (inf) V:1.000000 (inf) All:1.000000 (inf)`. Thank you! :)

Comment: You should put this as the answer. An absolute essential piece of information when calculating SSIM.